# prolog 'once member' not working

Tags: prolog

I have a method that takes in a string and converts it into a sentence to then be used within my program, but I am trying to make it quit/exit out if I enter 'quit/exit/halt/q', however it doesn't seem to be working, any help?

```
read_sentence([FirstWord|RestOfSentence]) :-
    readSentence([FirstWord|RestOfSentence]).

readSentence(quit).
readSentence([FirstWord|RestOfSentence]) :-
    get0(Char),
    once(member(FirstWord,[quit,exit,q])),
    readWord(Char,FirstWord,NextChar),
    readRestOfSentence(FirstWord,NextChar,RestOfSentence).
```

Im trying to use the once member call to exit out, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want. Your code is messy. `readSentence/1` once takes a list and once a string as argument. The definitions of `readRestOfSentence` and `readWord` are not given and the first clause doen't do anything
.

Comment: Instead of using once for exiting you should use stop clauses like your `readSentence(quit)` clause to exit.

Comment: *it doesn't seem to be working*... can you be more specific? What does it do or not do? And why do you think you need to use `once/1`?

Comment: if i enter ? readSentence([quit]), I want the program to notice the string 'quit' and exit out of the method and return true

Comment: Then you should have `readSentence([quit]).` not `readSentence(quit).` as your `readSentence/1` predicate base case clause.

Comment: `get0/0` is 1970s. Rather use `get_char/1/2` instead.